# Cannot view Territory fields with Manage Territories setting enabled

Tags: profile, permissions, territory-management, custom-profile

We are using Enterprise Territory Management (aka Territory Management 2.0). We have an existing profile that is setup to manage territories. The users in this profile can view and edit territories.

We created a new profile, copying our functioning territory management profile, and verified that the Manage Territories checkbox is checked. However, when these users go to Manage Territories in settings, and click on a territory, Salesforce does not show any fields.

Here's what I see when I try to view an existing Territory:

[image]

Here's what I see when I try to edit the same Territory:

[image]

I tried checking "View All Data" and "Modify All Data" permissions, but it made no difference.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Try checking page layout assignments and object perms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out (thanks @crmprogdev), the page would not display correctly because the profile was not assigned to the page layout. I never thought to look for this since I never created multiple page layouts. In fact, there is only one page layout and for some reason, it is not assigned to any profiles except for the one.